# .Net Core API : Asymmetric jwt key generation without sharing public key

Tags: .net, api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Am working on a JWT governed .net core web API. I am using asymmetric keys for encrypting and decrypting the keys. This API is for in-house clients. Generally we will have an unauthorised login call that would generate token on successful authentication after which it would relay them between each other. But here we want to secure all the calls.
So the question is, is there a way to generate these keys without sharing the public key but the key generation process to client team. So they can code their own key generation. Of course we should be able to authenticate it.

Comment: can you elaborate "But here we want to secure all the calls" ?. you mean even the login call ?

Comment: @CodingMytra yes  that is right

Comment: if you want to secure login itself then what is the point of login API. i don't understand the requirement here.

Comment: Exactly that was my question too. I will close this question. But I had to satisfy someone from security team at my workplace. I think you have pretty much answered it.